# Mysql- Select from two columns on a particular condition

Tags: php, mysql, count

I have two tables Table1 & Table2 that are connected to each other via xid and Yid.

**Table1**

```
xid(int)    category(varchar)       subcat(varchar)

1           Venue                   Resort
2           Venue                   Resort
3           Venue                   Resort
4           Venue                   Resort
5           Venue                   Resort
6           Venue                   Resort
7           Venue                   Banquet Hall
8           Venue                   Resort
9           Apparel                 Designer
```

**Table2**

```
Yid(int)    minp(varchar)           maxp(varchar)

1           800                     1000
2           900                     1200
3                                   1100
4           1300                    1600
5                                   1800
6           800                     2000
7           800                     1000
8           1500                    2100
9           15000                   60000
```

I have divided these vendors into three categories that is in first category vendors having price less than Rs. 1000. Second category is for vendors having price less than 1500 and more than 1000. and price more than 1500 into third category. Currently i am comparing price with maxp only and its working for me.

Query i am using for comparing with maxp is

```
SELECT xid from Table1,Table2 WHERE
Table1.xid=Table2.Yid 
AND category='venue' 
AND subcat='Resort' 
AND maxp<=1000
```

and Output i am getting is

```
xid

1
7
```

Now i want to compare price with both minp and maxp i want to count and fetch all those xid where minp or maxp any of these is less than 1000, between 1000 to 1500, more than 1500.

Expecting output for less than Rs. 1000

```
xid

1
2
6
7
```

Expecting output for more than Rs. 1000 and less than equal to 1500

```
xid

2
3
4
8
```

**Note:** For some reasons i can't change data type of minp and maxp from varchar to int or long also if minp is empty doesn't compare with it.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: which db? mysql or MSSQL (sql-server)?

Comment: Its mysql database

Answer (score 0):

You need to check in both columns according to your expected result.

```
SELECT xid 
from Table1 
INNER JOIN Table2 
        ON Table1.xid=Table2.Yid 
Where category='venue' 
AND subcat='Resort' 
AND (minp<=1000 or minp<=1000)
and minp <> ''
```

To find Rs. 1000 and less than equal to 1500

```
SELECT xid 
from Table1 
INNER JOIN Table2 
        ON Table1.xid=Table2.Yid 
Where category='venue' 
AND subcat='Resort' 
AND (minp > 1000 or maxp > 1000) and (minp <= 1500 or maxp <= 1500)
and minp <> ''
```

**Note :** Start using `INNER JOIN` syntax instead of old style comma separated join

Comment: i have used both of your queries...both are not working for minp and maxp...selecting all the rows....

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use something like this:

```
   SELECT xid , CATEGORY, SUBCAT, minp, maxp
    , CASE WHEN COALESCE(minp,0)<=1000  OR COALESCE(maxp,0)<=1000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS CAT1
    , CASE WHEN (COALESCE(minp,0)>1000 AND COALESCE(minp,0)<=1500) OR (COALESCE(maxp,0)>1000 AND COALESCE(maxp,0)<=1500) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS CAT2
    , CASE WHEN COALESCE(minp,0)>1500 OR COALESCE(maxp,0)>1500 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS CAT3                        
from Table1 A
INNER JOIN Table2 B ON A.xid=B.Yid 
;
```

Output:

```
xid CATEGORY SUBCAT   minp  maxp    CAT1    CAT2    CAT3
1   Venue   Resort    800   1000    1   0   0
2   Venue   Resort    900   1200    1   1   0
3   Venue   Resort    NULL  1100    1   1   0
4   Venue   Resort    1300  1600    0   1   1
5   Venue   Resort    NULL  1800    1   0   1
6   Venue   Resort    800    2000   1   0   1
7   Venue   BanquetH  800   1000    1   0   0
8   Venue   Resort    1500  2100    0   1   1
9   Apparel Designer 15000  60000   0   0   1
```

To add count for each category you could use:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
 (SELECT xid , CATEGORY, SUBCAT, minp, maxp
    , CASE WHEN COALESCE(minp,0)<=1000  OR COALESCE(maxp,0)<=1000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS CAT1
    , CASE WHEN (COALESCE(minp,0)>1000 AND COALESCE(minp,0)<=1500) OR (COALESCE(maxp,0)>1000 AND COALESCE(maxp,0)<=1500) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS CAT2
    , CASE WHEN COALESCE(minp,0)>1500 OR COALESCE(maxp,0)>1500 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS CAT3                    
from Table1 A
INNER JOIN Table2 B ON A.xid=B.Yid ) X
CROSS JOIN (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN CAT1=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CAT1_RC
                ,SUM(CASE WHEN CAT2=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CAT2_RC
                , SUM(CASE WHEN CAT3=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CAT3_RC
              FROM (SELECT xid , CATEGORY, SUBCAT, minp, maxp
                     , CASE WHEN COALESCE(minp,0)<=1000  OR COALESCE(maxp,0)<=1000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS CAT1
                     , CASE WHEN (COALESCE(minp,0)>1000 AND COALESCE(minp,0)<=1500) OR (COALESCE(maxp,0)>1000 AND COALESCE(maxp,0)<=1500) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS CAT2
                     , CASE WHEN COALESCE(minp,0)>1500 OR COALESCE(maxp,0)>1500 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS CAT3                   
                     from Table1 A
                     INNER JOIN Table2 B ON A.xid=B.Yid) X1
              ) Y
              ;
```

Output:

```
+-----+----------+-----------+-------+-------+------+------+------+---------+---------+---------+
| xid | CATEGORY |  SUBCAT   | minp  | maxp  | CAT1 | CAT2 | CAT3 | CAT1_RC | CAT2_RC | CAT3_RC |
+-----+----------+-----------+-------+-------+------+------+------+---------+---------+---------+
|   1 | Venue    | Resort    | 800   |  1000 |    1 |    0 |    0 |       6 |       4 |       5 |
|   2 | Venue    | Resort    | 900   |  1200 |    1 |    1 |    0 |       6 |       4 |       5 |
|   3 | Venue    | Resort    | NULL  |  1100 |    1 |    1 |    0 |       6 |       4 |       5 |
|   4 | Venue    | Resort    | 1300  |  1600 |    0 |    1 |    1 |       6 |       4 |       5 |
|   5 | Venue    | Resort    | NULL  |  1800 |    1 |    0 |    1 |       6 |       4 |       5 |
|   6 | Venue    | Resort    | 800   |  2000 |    1 |    0 |    1 |       6 |       4 |       5 |
|   7 | Venue    | Banquet H | 800   |  1000 |    1 |    0 |    0 |       6 |       4 |       5 |
|   8 | Venue    | Resort    | 1500  |  2100 |    0 |    1 |    1 |       6 |       4 |       5 |
|   9 | Apparel  | Designer  | 15000 | 60000 |    0 |    0 |    1 |       6 |       4 |       5 |
+-----+----------+-----------+-------+-------+------+------+------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to try this.

1.You want to compare price with both minp and maxp i want to count and fetch all those xid where minp or maxp any of these is less than 1000, between 1000 to 1500, more than 1500.

> SELECT t1.xid from Table1 t1,Table2 t2 WHERE t1.xid=t2.Yid AND
>   t1.category='venue' AND t1.subcat='Resort' AND (t2.maxp<=1000 or
>   t2.minp<=1000)

2. output for more than Rs. 1000 and less than equal to 1500

> SELECT t1.xid from Table1 t1,Table2 t2 WHERE t1.xid=t2.Yid AND
>   t1.category='venue' AND t1.subcat='Resort' AND ((t2.maxp>=1000 and
>   t2.maxp <= 1500) OR (t2.minp>=1000 and t2.minp<=1500)